# Where does internal file go when App install is external?

Tags: java, android, file, storage

I want my file to stay with the App, no matter where it is installed. I have preferred install location as external. I write and read an internal file (I do not care if it is gone on next run). Will it be stored on the external drive if the install location is external?

Lines to create (both internal and external file):

FileOutputStream fIntFile = openFileOutput("textIntFile.txt", 
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //MODE_PRIVATE over-written each time

File testExtFile = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "TestExtFile.txt");
if (!testExtFile.exists() testExtFile.createNewFile();

What I would like to know is, if the user is short on internal memory, and so installs the App on the external drive (usually SD card?), then this file would ideally also go to the external drive. If the device does not have external drive, and lots of internal space, then everything will go on the external drive.

I suppose, my alternative, is to test for location of App, and if there is external drive, and if there is lots of internal space.

And the code above was that what I found for opening an Internal file and an external file. Any better suggestions would be very welcomr

Comment: Show the relevant code you use to write a file. And tell us full path.

Comment: Further your file will never be in the path of your app.